# Why is the "Templates" directory still not working in Freya's Pantheon files?

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files

I was wondering, why the files dropped under `~/Templates` do not appear in the "New" context menu of Pantheon files. While investigating this, I came across the following bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1356235

It says, that this issue has been fixed for Pantheon files 0.2. The version of my `pantheon-files` package is `0.2.4-0~r1980+pkg47~ubuntu0.3.1.1`, according to `apt`. So why does Pantheon only offer "Directory" and "Empty file" in its "New" context menu, while there is a `Letter.tex` file in my `~/Templates` directory?

Comment: I have just checked this on a 32-bit install of Freya with the same version of Files and seems to work OK for me using simple text files at least.  If you put a folder in ~/Templates it also creates a new submenu on the "New" context menu.  Have you tried it just with new empty files created in Templates and named e.g. "template.txt"?  In case there is something weird about Latex files preventing it from working, in which case a new bug should be raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be [another localization-related bug in Pantheon files](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1608229) that needs to be fixed. In the meantime, the following work-around has proven to work: Rename your `~/Templates` directory, where `Templates` refers to whatever the word for "templates" in your language of choice is, such that this directory's name actually becomes the english word `Templates`. So for example, if you're on a German installation of Freya, simply rename `~/Vorlagen` to `~/Templates`.